# Overlapping dates in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Previously I wanted to get time slots between `$starttime` and `$endtime`, divided by `$duration` value.

We managed to get it working with this code :

```
$starttime = '9:00';  // your start time
$endtime = '21:00';  // End time
$duration = '30';  // split by 30 mins

$array_of_time = array ();
$start_time    = strtotime ($starttime); //change to strtotime
$end_time      = strtotime ($endtime); //change to strtotime

$add_mins  = $duration * 60;

while ($start_time <= $end_time) // loop between time
{
   $array_of_time[] = date ("h:i", $start_time);
   $start_time += $add_mins; // to check endtie=me
}

$new_array_of_time = array ();
for($i = 0; $i < count($array_of_time) - 1; $i++)
{
    $new_array_of_time[] = '' . $array_of_time[$i] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$i + 1];
}
```

Now the issue is I don't want to show the timeslots that match dates in my **appointments** table.

To get the Appointments matching that date , i did :

```
$appointments = Appointment::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('appointment_datetime', $date->toDateString() )->get();
```

Now this returns me all appointments, ... in each appointment we have a column **appointment_start** and **appointment_end** , witch are formated in **TIME** .

Next step would be to check all appointment for matching timeslots ... and this is where I am stuck.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the code with this one:

```
$starttime = '9:00';  // your start time
$endtime = '21:00';  // End time
$duration = '30';  // split by 30 mins

$array_of_time = array ();
$start_time    = strtotime ($starttime); //change to strtotime
$end_time      = strtotime ($endtime); //change to strtotime

$add_mins  = $duration * 60; // seconds

while ($start_time <= $end_time) // loop between time
{
 $array_of_time[] = date ("h:i", $start_time);
 $start_time += $add_mins; // to check endtie=me
}

// Here I am getting the indexes of the time slot which has appointment
$indexes_to_be_skipped = array();
foreach($appointments as $appointment) {
  for($i=0;$i<count($array_of_time); $i++) {
    if($array_of_time[$i] == date ("h:i", strtotime($appointment['appointment_time_start']))) {
      $indexes_to_be_skipped[$i] = $i;
    }
  }
}

$new_array_of_time = array ();
for($i = 0; $i < count($array_of_time) - 1; $i++)
{
  $new_array_of_time[] = '' . $array_of_time[$i] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$i + 1];

  // check if current time slot has already appointment
  if(isset($indexes_to_be_skipped[$i])) {
    // then remove it
    unset($new_array_of_time[$i]);
  }
}

// resetting index
$narray_of_time = $new_array_of_time;
$new_array_of_time = array();
foreach($narray_of_time as $item) {
  $new_array_of_time[] = $item;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
<?php
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); // the date you need to check
$starttime = \Carbon\Carbon::create($date->year, $date->month, $date->day, 9,0);  // your start time
$endtime = \Carbon\Carbon::create($date->year, $date->month, $date->day, 21,0); // end time
$add_mins  = 60; // minutes to add to each meeting
$array_of_time = [];
$current_time = $starttime->copy();

while($current_time->isBefore($endtime)){
    // check if we have record between current and current + $add_mins
    // I suppose appointment_datetime is a datetime field in database
    if(!Appointment::where('user_id', $user->id)->whereBetween('appointment_datetime', [$current_time, $current_time->copy()->addMinute($add_mins)])->count()){
        $array_of_time[] = $current_time->format('H:i') . ' - ' . $current_time->copy()->addMinute($add_mins)->format('H:i');
    }
    $current_time->addMinute($add_mins);
}
```